# How do I solve this missing return statement error?

Tags: java, return

I'm having trouble with a return statement. I've already got 2 in the method which returns an int value if the details that the user enters matches a apartment object.

My issue is that why am I still getting a missing return statement error when I've got 2 already. I know a question similar to this has been asked already but I really don't understand how it works.

```
public static int search(){
    int none = 55;
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a bedroom number ");
    int bedroom = user.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a bathroom number ");
    int bathroom = user.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your rental budget");
    int rentalAmount = user.nextInt();
    
    for( int x = 0; x < object.length;++x){
        if(object[x].getNumBathrooms() == bathroom && object[x].getNumBedrooms() == bedroom  
                && (object[x].getRentalAmount() <= rentalAmount)){
                                 return x;
        }else{
            return none;           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should begin by indenting your code.

Comment: Add a return after the for-loop. You need to specify what is returned if the for-loop runs zero times.

Comment: It's possible for a `for` loop to NEVER RUN...therefore it's possible that neither of your two `return` statements are hit.  You need a `return` statement at the bottom of the function as well.  Another way to approach this is to set a variable to the the return value inside the loop, then toggle a flag to exit the loop, and finally have only ONE RETURN at the bottom of the function that returns the value.

Comment: Why do you have the final for loop? It will only loop once before it returns (when x is 0, it will either return on the if-statement or the else-statement). It should just be replaced with a single if-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `for` loop, eliminate the `else` branch. Then put the `return none;` statement just after the end of the `for` loop.

```
for (int x = 0; x < object.length; ++x) {
    if (object[x].getNumBathrooms() == bathroom &&
        object[x].getNumBedrooms() == bedroom &&
        object[x].getRentalAmount() <= rentalAmount)
    {
        return x;
    }
}
return none;
```